Excel - IF formula TRUE statement output changing based on FALSE argument? (with DROP and VSTACK output)
I have a variable height VSTACK output which can or not have a leading blank value:
<blank>
1
<blank>
2
3
<blank>

I'm trying to remove the leading blank like this:
IF(INDEX(<vstack_output>;1)="";
    DROP(<vstack_output>;1);
    <vstack_output>)

Which evaluates to TRUE and removes the first cell shifting the other values up, but for some reason maintains the last cell in the output with an #N/A error:
1
<blank>
2
3
<blank>
#N/A     // This should not be here

The odd thing is that I've noticed that changing the value of the IF's FALSE statement to a random string...
   IF(INDEX(<vstack_output>;1)="";
        DROP(<vstack_output>;1);
        "random string instead of vstack output")

...actually makes the TRUE statement work as intended, giving the following desired output (note how it not only removes the initial blank, also trims the column, making it once cell shorter):
1
<blank>
2
3
<blank>

The above is also the same output as if I just do DROP(<vstack_output>;1) with no IF involved.
I'm assuming it might have something to do with the way arrays are stored in memory, but otherwise I'm clueless. Any idea of why the TRUE if output might be changing based on the FALSE argument?

So you're looking for why, or looking for a solution to a problem?

I see a lot of VSTACK including blanks problems. Maybe it's a good idea to post samples of the two ranges you're stacking and your end goal with that. What's the function of the blanks in your output?

=LET(v,<VSTACKoutput>,IF(@v="",DROP(v,1),v)) avoiding INDEX makes it work like you want.

It is for a printed chart, the blanks are merely meant to separate categories. The trailing blank does not bother me, but the leading blank messes up the chart. Thank you for your solution! It works! Did not even know you could use @ like that. Cheers!

@HigoChumbo, would you please test with INDEX(<VSTACKoutput>; 1; 1) if you get a chance? I'm curious to know. If it doesn't please let me know the Excel version you're using. Thanks!

You can use implicit intersection to evaluate the top-left cell of the array:
=DROP(<vstack_output>,@<vstack_output>="")

And as suggested by @P.b, chuck a LET() variable in the equation just to avoid a 2nd calculation of your vstack-variable.
=LET(_r,<vstack_output>,DROP(_r,@_r="")


Did not even know about implicit intersection (even when I do use the @ for dynamic tables, thought it was just syntax for "current row"). Was using @P.b's solution =LET(v,,IF(@v="",DROP(v,1),v)), but it's actually really clever how you use the boolean to evaluate to "1" in the Drop. Thank you!!

it seems like the issue you're facing is related to how Excel or Google Sheets handles dynamic arrays when using functions like VSTACK and DROP with an IF statement the #N/A error you're seeing likely occurs because when you conditionally remove the first row of your array, Excel/Sheets might not correctly resize the array, leaving extra space that shows up as #N/A when you replace the array in the IF statement with a static value, it forces Excel/Sheets to correctly handle the array size, which is why the issue disappears

So what formula should I instead use to remove the first cell in the VSTACK output only if it´s an empty string ("")? I could FILTER with NOT(ISNA()) but seems very unclean. Don't want to hide other potential errors.

It's not VSTACK related, it's the combination IF/INDEX and two different size output options for if. =IF(INDEX({1;2},1),{1;2;3},{1;2;3;4})

I think you can use MATCH(TRUE,data<>"",0,1) to find the first non-blank value, then use MATCH(TRUE,data<>"",0,-1) to find the last non-blank value, and then slice the array using DROP and TAKE.
=LET(
    data, A1:A9,
    start, XMATCH(TRUE, data <> "", 0, 1),
    end, XMATCH(TRUE, data <> "", 0, -1),
    DROP(TAKE(data, end), start - 1)
)



Hello again, I couldn't reproduce the error on Mac with regular ranges, but was able to with output from VSTACK (as seen in my answer). I'm currently on insider build. I remember you being Mac Excel user - could you please test it if you're on a different version? Thanks!

INDEX(vstack_out, 1, 1) also may work
Adding the column parameter to INDEX seems to eliminate the error. I'm not sure whether it works on all version, it work on my Mac Microsoft 365.

My experience with Excel is limited, but I think INDEX(vstack_out, 1, 1) is treated as a single value whereas INDEX(vstack_out, 1) is treated as an array with a single value.

So due to 'broadcasting/lifting' (I recently became aware of this term, relating behavior mentioned in doc for CHOOSE) behavior when an array is given as a parameter instead of a single value, IF expands the array from VSTACK.


Perhaps more experienced users could explain this better.


Yes, I am pretty sure INDEX(data, 1,1) will fix the problem in all versions of excel. I check the debugger in Excel lab. turns out in  IF("TRUE", value_if_true, value_if_false). value_if_true will be returned while value_if_false will never be evaluated. while in IF({"TRUE"}, value_if_true, value_if_false), both value_if_true and value_if_false will be evaluated. and if value_if_true and value_if_false are arrays of different sizes. e.g. if len(value_if_true) < len(value_if_false), excel will just fill "NA" in value_if_true.

Thank you! Though I have been using Excel Lab, haven't used the debugger much. I'll start using it more.
